# Promise returning deferred.promise test using Mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

### Bot Info

- SDK Platform: Node.js

### Issue Description

### Code Example

```
resolveMeetingRoomFreeTime: function (session, args) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        kgService.getFreeMeetingRooms(session.conversationData.floorEntityList,
            session.conversationData.roomEntityList,
            session.conversationData.meetingStartTimestamp,
            session.conversationData.meetingEndTimestamp,
            session.conversationData.meetingStartTime,
            session.conversationData.meetingEndTime,
            session.conversationData.meetingDuration)
            .then(function (roomReservationList) {
                **let returnResults = roomReservationList;
                session.conversationData.meetingRoomAvailabilityList = roomReservationList;
                setTimeout(function () { resolve(returnResults); }, 1000);**
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("There is error from getFreeMeetingRooms() "+error);
            });
    }
    )
}

Method getFreeMeetingRooms() looks like as follows. 

    getFreeMeetingRooms: function (nearestFloorEntity, roomEntityList, startEpoch, endEpoch, startHour, endHour, meetingDuration) {
        let deferred = Q.defer();
        let query = function (resolve, reject) {

            graphDB.cypher({
                query: cypherQuery,
                params: {
                    nearestFloorEntity, roomEntityList, startEpoch, endEpoch, startHour, endHour, meetingDuration
                }

            }, function (err, results) {
                return deferred.resolve(results);
            });
            query();
            return deferred.promise;

        }


My test case using Mocha and Sion Stub:

it('Should return default value for resolveMeetingRoomFreeTime()', function () {
    let args = {};
    let session = {
        conversationData: {
            roomEntityList: [{ id: "ABC", name: "ABC", capacity: 8}],
            floorEntityList: "9",
            meetingStartTimestamp: 1521659679948,
            meetingEndTimestamp: 1521781200000,
            meetingStartTime: 1514815200000,
            meetingEndTime: 1514847600000,
            meetingDuration: 30
        }
    };

    //stubbing call for getFreeMeetingRooms()
    var stub = sinon.stub(calendarNeo4jService, "getFreeMeetingRooms")
   .withArgs(session.conversationData.floorEntityList,
        session.conversationData.roomEntityList,
        session.conversationData.meetingStartTimestamp,
        session.conversationData.meetingEndTimestamp,
        session.conversationData.meetingStartTime,
        session.conversationData.meetingEndTime,
        session.conversationData.meetingDuration);

    var error= calendarEntityResolver.resolveMeetingRoomFreeTime(session, args)
    error.then(function name(params) {
    })
    .then(function (error) { 
     });
});
```

Questions:

1. Not sure if using stub is correct if I need to skil DB call graphDB.cypher from method getFreeMeetingRooms().
2. How do I test block of code from resolveMeetingRoomFreeTime() which is highlighted.
3. If stubbing  kgService.getFreeMeetingRooms is correct the how would test catch block.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking how to test an async function using mocha. If that's true, you only need to return your promise inside the `it` function. Mocha will wait for the promise to resolve or reject before marking it successful, which will also allow assertions in the `then` function.

Comment: No. I am not asking how to test an async function using mocha but instead how to test this specific scenario which involves  sinon.stub()

Comment: Basically I am not sure how to test resolveMeetingRoomFreeTime() by using sinon.stub and sinon.mock or anything else. There is lots of promise chain happening here.